# Laravel 5.4: Error 403 al cargar imagenes desde la carpeta /public con asset

Tags: laravel

Esta es mi primera consulta, así que les pido paciencia. Busqué primero a ver si había un caso similar, y no pude encontrarlo.

Tengo una Web App con laravel 5.4. El problema que tengo radica en que las llamadas a recursos de la carpeta public me están retornando 403. Lo extraño de la situación es que tengo entornos replicados de producción, QA y desarrollo con Git, y esto no me ocurre ni en producción, ni en QA (producción y QA están en un hosting compartido con una réplica en AWS).

Voy en detalle:

1. Mis recursos de imagen los tengo alojados en /var/www/miSitio/public/images/
2. En algunos casos mis llamadas a estos recursos son a imágenes estáticas, y otras a rutas que vienen en el objeto desde el controlador
3. Sucede lo mismo con los recursos que tengo en Storage/app/public, y ya hice `php artisan storage::link`, y los permisos están en 775

Para poner un ejemplo simple, tengo el logo en la pantalla de login, lo llamo desde el blade con:

`<img src="{{ asset("images/icon/logo.png") }}" alt="Logo" class="align-self-center"/>`

1. Ya revisé mi configuración de permisos, la carpeta /public tiene www-data:www-data y permisos 750
2. Mi configuración de apache del vhost no ha cambiado
3. Tengo PHP y sus mods actualizados
4. El único cambio reciente fue de composer, actualizado a 2.0.8

He revisado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido y no doy con el problema. Si alguien pudiera echarme una mano en alguna configuración que pueda revisar, lo agradecería enormemente. Como dije al principio, esto me pasa hace dos días solo en entorno de desarrollo, en QA y producción no me ocurre.

Mi entorno de desarrollo es una máquina virtual debian 9, y mi instalación es a partir de Apache 2, PHP 7.2 y MariaDB; trabajo así para emular un entorno de producción en AWS (y por extensión en cualquier hosting). Mi ruta de vhost esta en /var/www/webs/misitio. Esto me facilita la gestión de otros proyectos. Si es necesario que suba el archivo de Vhost, solo avísenme.

En mis otros proyectos en Laravel no ocurre esta situación. Probe clonar de nuevo mi repositorio en la VM local, haciendo una instalación limpia de Laravel, y la situación persiste.

Cualquier sugerencia que puedan darme para ayudarme a resolver este caso, será bien recibido.

Quedo atento. Gracias!

Comment: Si intentas con la url absoluta sucede lo mismo?

Comment: Hola @NicolasAldana, es correcto, sucede lo mismo.

Comment: Cuando visualizas en el navegador ¿Qué ruta te marca en el HTML? Es decir, que dirección te pone en `<img src="" alt="">` ? Ta aparece la ruta correcta u otra ruta?

Comment: Hola @EdgarGC, en la ruta del archivo desde el inspector de codigo es: `<img src="http://misitio.local/images/icon/logo.png" alt="logo" />`, y en producción la ruta es idéntica, solo cambia "misitio.local" por "misitio.com". Ahora que lo pienso, en producción tenía una situación con el retorno a una ruta de una funcion Ajax, en la cual debí modificar el .htaccess para añadir reescritura a las rutas que apuntan a "public", sin embargo, en desarrollo no necesito tener .htaccess, nunca me hizo falta. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Encontré el origen del problema. Surgió la respuesta por pasar por alto algo curioso con el problema en si mismo; me ocurría con las imágenes en formato .jpg, .gif y .png, pero no así con las .webp.

Les decía en la formulación del problema que yo no utilizaba .htaccess en el sitio. Por alguna razón desde mi repositorio descargue un .htaccess que está en /public (quiero suponer que el hosting lo generó automáticamente, pues no lo tengo en el origen del proyecto). Este .htaccess tenía una línea que indica lo siguiente:

`RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]`

Lo que estaba provocando que aunque tengo bien los permisos, propietario y grupo de la carpeta /public, la bandera F estaba prohibiendo el accesso a los recursos. Solo bastaba con quitar el Flag F. Todo funciona a la perfección, la linea quedó así:

`RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [NC]`

Igual les agradezco a todos su empeño y observaciones. Espero esto pueda ayudar a otros con una situación similar. :)

Comment: No olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, así los demás nos enteramos esta es la solución